# Is there an easy way to "restart" a tmux pane?

Tags: tmux

Assume I have a `tmux` (1.7) window split as follows:

```
 ________________________
|           1            |
|                        |
|-----------+------------|
|     2     |      3     |
|___________|____________|
```

Now, the vertical sizes have been customized, so it's by no means one of the default layouts.

On occasion, when a program gets stuck or when you reboot a machine to which you connected via `ssh`, the pane "hangs". I.e. nothing other than `kill-pane` appears to work.

However, since there is no easy way to rebuild above split configuration once pane #1 has been `kill-pane`d, I'd like to "restart" it.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Looking at the manual, the command `respawn-pane` struck me, but it turned out that this didn't work. Reading more closely, it turned out that `respawn-pane -k` was the answer, since it would *kill* the running command.

This way a pane can be "restarted" and spawned anew in place.

So `<prefix>`+<kbd>:</kbd> and then enter `respawn-pane -k` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Or use without `-k` if you created the pane in `remain-on-exit` mode and killed the command yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a way to rebuild a layout - `list-windows` gives you a layout description for all windows in a session and `select-layout` can digest parse the string and set the layout appropriately (see `select-layout` in the man page `tmux(1)`).

As for your ssh problem - ssh servers should close connection once the system shuts down (although I have seen some Linux distributions which somehow mess up the proper behaviour by not shutting down the ssh daemon and running sessions properly) - if that is the case, see the `ESCAPE CHARACTERS` section (and other places referring to it) in `ssh(1)` - escape character followed by `.` (a dot) forcefully terminates the connection on the client side. Of course it doesn't help if you just spawned the pane with `ssh` running in it, but if you experience the problem more often, perhaps you'd rather want to run a shell in the pane and call ssh from therein.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it adds value. But here's why the escape characters are not necessarily a good idea: using an ssh session in order to connect to a tmux session which has open ssh connections. Then you suddenly need to think about how to send the escape character beyond first ssh connection to reach the inner one(s). And btw, I usually run ssh from a shell.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing as when you are running nested tmux sessions. Either you have different escape characters in the outer and inner session (be it ssh or tmux one) or you just send the escape character twice - which makes it go as a single one into the nested session (hard-wired behaviour for ssh, configurable in tmux).